# Get 64-bit values fromRegistry in Driver Mode

Tags: windows, registry, 64-bit, driver

How can I get 64-bit values fromRegistry in Driver Mode.
The 32-bits values(REG_DWORD) i can get. But 64-bit values(REG_QWORD) can't. 
Here a code:

```
RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_TABLE parameters[2];
RtlZeroMemory(parameters, sizeof(parameters));

parameters[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT;
parameters[0].Name = L"MaxTotalSize";
parameters[0].EntryContext = &Globals.g_MaxTotalSize;
parameters[0].DefaultType = REG_DWORD;  //But REG_QWORD doesn't work, what i must to write?
parameters[0].DefaultData = &Globals.g_MaxTotalSize;
parameters[0].DefaultLength = 4;        //And here what I must to write?

status = RtlQueryRegistryValues(
        RTL_REGISTRY_ABSOLUTE | RTL_REGISTRY_OPTIONAL,
        RegistryPath->Buffer,
        parameters,
        NULL,
        NULL
        );
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you attempt to read `REG_QWORD`

Comment: Thank you for you attention, the code is below...

Answer (score 0):

Here I trying to get 64-bit value from registry:

```
RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_TABLE parameters[2];
RtlZeroMemory(parameters, sizeof(parameters));

parameters[0].Flags = RTL_QUERY_REGISTRY_DIRECT;
parameters[0].Name = L"MaxTotalSize";
parameters[0].EntryContext = &Globals.g_MaxTotalSize;
parameters[0].DefaultType = REG_QWORD;  
parameters[0].DefaultData = &Globals.g_MaxTotalSize;
parameters[0].DefaultLength = 8;        

status = RtlQueryRegistryValues(
        RTL_REGISTRY_ABSOLUTE | RTL_REGISTRY_OPTIONAL,
        RegistryPath->Buffer,
        parameters,
        NULL,
        NULL
        );
```

Globals.g_MaxTotalSize have **ULONGLONG** type